# Prove that any set of 27 six-digit positive integers must have three subsets with the same sum.

Tags: proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

So I know this is a pigeon hole problem, however, I am struggling with what the holes and pigeons should be. I originally was thinking that there should be 13 holes because there's 27 numbers and we needed to fit at least two into each hole (26) plus another number to get the third subset. But this doesn't make sense to me any more because that would mean we are acting as if there's only 27 possible subsets.

Now I believe there are 55 possible sums for each group of 27 six-digit numbers. I got this by doing 9+9+9+9+9+9 + 1 for 0 this would make sense if we now use the numbers as holes and the possible sums as pigeons because there are 27 numbers and 27*2=54 and then the +1 means that there is a third number in the subset. However this doesn't make sense to me as much now because then we are acting as if the last 5 digits can't be zero. So, does anyone have some ideas of what I should use for pigeons/holes?

Comment: I'm confused as to how "three subsets with the same sum" lead to your "55 possible sums for each group  of 27 dix-digit numbers". It seems to me that you did "3 numbers with the same digit sum" instead? Can you add more details about what you're doing?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554404/how-many-id-numbers-must-you-have-to-guarantee-that-at-least-two-of-them-sum-to I was using logic in the solution to a different problem I found here to back that up. so I did 9+9+9+9+9+9+1 for 0 now I realize it can't have a plus one because 0 isn't a positive 6 digit integer so the rest of that idea kind of falls apart at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I suspect you're not stating the problem correctly / as intended. If you've rephrased the problem, let me know.

---

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, write out your working and thought process to demonstrate where you're at.)

There are $ 2^{27}$ subsets of these 27 six-digit positive integers. This is our pigeons.

For our holes, they are the possible values of these subsets, which range from $0$ to $27 \times 999999$.

Hence, by PP, one of these holes must contain at least $X$ pigeons. Hence we are done.

Comment: The title was the original problem. The rest of the post was my thought processes in an attempt to solve it. If the set is one of positive integers then we should exclude 0 in the range from 0 to 27 right and instead its a range from 300,000 to 27*999,999? Excluding 1-299,999 because the smallest a 6 digit integer can be is 100,000 since leading zeros can't be included on an integer.

Comment: I realize now minimum of range of sums would be 100,000 not 300,000 because of subsets of 1 and 2 elements.

Comment: I think regardless of whether the minimum is 0 or 100,000 the result is the same where there are more pigeons than 2*the number of holes. So thank you for your help.

Comment: @Anon365 You're (mostly) right. Note that I included the empty set (which yes, we could exclude to have a tighter bound), so I left the min as 0. In particular, $X > 3$, which is why I didn't need to tighten up the ranges.